# Probleme to install Superdesk Newsroom

Tags: github, superdesk

I'm trying to install newsromm from  https://github.com/superdesk/newsroom 
with installation with NPM I've these errors :

```
npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update! 
npm WARN deprecated nomnom@1.6.2: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.

> node-sass@4.9.0 install /root/newsroom/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:596
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/root/newsroom/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:594:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:240:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:564:3)
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN newsroom No repository field.
npm WARN newsroom No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.9.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.9.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-07-01T18_21_45_224Z-debug.log
```

and with installation with YARN everything looks good :

```
yarn install v1.7.0
(node:40422) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > react-toggle@4.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "prop-types@^15.3.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 236.13s.
```

but when I start the app , I'v this message:

```
honcho start -p 5050
18:17:07 system      | web.1 started (pid=52710)
18:17:07 system      | websocket.1 started (pid=52711)
18:17:08 websocket.1 | /usr/bin/python: No module named superdesk
18:17:08 system      | websocket.1 stopped (rc=1)
18:17:08 system      | sending SIGTERM to web.v
```

How can I resolve this ?

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newsroom is just a plugin for Superdesk. You need to install Superdesk as well from https://github.com/superdesk/superdesk.